# what is the use and the locations of nacelle hinge bracket?

Tags: jet-engine

i have seen on the webs about the additive manufacturing about this bracket here but I have no clues on where is it located and whats the purpose of it. Do give me any links if there are actually any if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're talking about the part below. The part was changed from cast steel to titanium DMLS additive manufacturing technology.

[image: Nacelle hinge]

Image from belement.co.il

The hinge is used to hold the engine nacelle cowling when opened. YOu can see four of them (older versions) on top of the open cowing in the image below:

[image: open cowling]

Image from article.wn.com

Comment: omg thanks so much